# properly encode and decode json results (php to js)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to encode my array results to json and pass them to a ajax successful event in javascript.

```
PHP

    $results = array(
        "time1" => 1,
        "time2" => 2,

    );
    echo json_encode($results);
```

JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY

```
   $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "actions/myphp.php",
             data: PassArray,
             dataType: 'json',
             beforeSend: function (html) { // this happens before actual call
             //    alert(html);
             },
             success: function (html) { 
                 // $("#loginoutcome").text(html);
                // alert(html);
                 var obj  = jQuery.parseJSON(html ); 
                // Now the two will work
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                    alert(key + ' ' + value);
                });

             },
```

Leaving the JQUERY.parseJSON there throws a json parse unexpected character, I dont think I that I need it anyway as I specify in the dataType: 'json', above?.. 
But how can I retrieve the values ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pass datatype as JSON, jQuery will give you back the JSON object, you don't have to parse it anymore.

So make it like this:

```
success: function (obj) { 
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                alert(key + ' ' + value);
            });

         },
```

If you know its time1 or time2, you can do this:

```
success: function (obj) { 
            alert(obj.time1);
            alert(obj.time2);
         },
```

Comment: thanks, good answer the other problem that I had is that I had more than one echo and I needed only one.